# Xcode / simulator won't run 2 different targets of same app

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

OK, so I'm working on building a "lite" version of my app so I duplicated the target and changed the product name to lite. The problem I'm having is when I build "target one" on the iOS 6.1 simulator it runs and works fine. Then if I stop and switch schemes to build and run "target two" it builds successfully with no errors but will not run on the simulator. If I delete "target one's" app from the simulator and then try and run "target two" it now works. However now "target one" won't run. I know this because I have set 2 separate icons for both targets and I can see visually which one is running on the simulator. Did I miss something when I duplicated the target? I setup the new plist for "target two" to match the name in the build settings. I don't know what is going on. Any suggestions?

Oh, one last thing; when ever one of the targets "run" fails it shows `error: failed to attach to process ID 0`

I also noticed that the scheme name says "myAppName copy" for the second target even though I changed the product and target name when I duplicated it.

UPDATE:
I tried cleaning both targets and still same result. I have to delete the app every time to run the other target.

Comment: Did you change the bundle id for the new target?

Comment: You Rock!!! That worked and just ended my 2 hours of frustration. Do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the bundle identifier for the new target.